# How to resolve an Infinite loop in my modified BFS program?

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

I have set up a code that will navigate a graph based on values associated with each edge between nodes. Each edge has a color and type associated with it, and I should only follow an edge in my BFS if the color or type matches the last color or Type. The first Color/Type is set by whatever first edge is followed. However, when I run my specific code, I get an infite loop someplace in the setup that will not resolve.

I Have tried setting up different loop styles and looping through my list using iterators instead of the current for loop, neither works and both result in the same error.

queue  Q;

```
Q.push(neededNode);
string lastType = "";
string lastColor = "";
while (!Q.empty()){
    node u = Q.front();
    Q.pop();
    for(auto& itr : adjacencyList[u.city]){ //cycle through the adjacency list
        for (auto& entry: nodeList){ //find the node for the entry
            if (entry.city == (itr).city){
                //Initial condition for setting color/type to follow
                if(lastType == "" || lastColor == ""){
                    lastColor = (itr).color;
                    lastType = (itr).type;
                    entry.state = true;
                    entry.distance = u.distance +1;
                    entry.parent = u.city;
                    cout << u.city << " " << lastColor << " " << lastType << endl;
                //If Types match
                }else if(lastType == (itr).type){
                    lastColor = (itr).color;
                    lastType = (itr).type;
                    entry.state = true;
                    entry.distance = u.distance +1;
                    entry.parent = u.city;
                    cout << u.city << " " << lastColor << " " << lastType << endl;
                //If colors match
                }else if(lastColor == (itr).color){
                    lastColor = (itr).color;
                    lastType = (itr).type;
                    entry.state = true;
                    entry.distance = u.distance +1;
                    entry.parent = u.city;
                    cout << u.city << " " << lastColor << " " << lastType << endl;
                }
                Q.push(entry);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, the code should run and stop running when complete, and I should be able to follow the parent values to the correct path. Currently, I get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Mark the nodes you have already seen to make sure you do not visit them again (and again), for example using your .state:

```
if (entry.city == (itr).city && !entry.state) {
    //Initial condition for setting color/type to follow
```